# Saving a DICOM image in PNG format

Tags: matlab, dicom

I have a `dicom` image which I read in `matlab` as:

```
I=dicomread('xyz.dcm');
```

In displaying it, I used the following command:

```
imshow(I,[])
```

What I want to ask about is, how can I write it through `imwrite`, such that I get the image as seen using the above `imshow` command?

I for instance tried this:

```
imwrite(I,'xyz.png','png');
```

but, get a **dark** image.

Any ideas on that?

Thanks.

Comment: What does a `BMP` file look like?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like dicom image has a 16-bit depth, which is larger than the usual 8-bit.
To verify that this is indeed the case type

```
>> class( I )
```

I would expect the output to be `uint16`.
If so, try:

```
imwrite( I, 'xyz.png', 'bitdepth', 16 );
```

Answer (score 1):

When you read the image, get the colormap as well

```
[I, map]=dicomread('xyz.dcm');
```

Now when you save it, give imwrite the colormap also.

```
imwrite(I,map,'xyz.png','png');
```

And by the way, the last png isn't necessary usually. MATLAB will see the .png extension and know to save it as a png.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I tried your solution I got the following error (the dcm file name is `000000.dcm`: `Error using imwrite>parse_inputs (line 529)
The colormap should have three columns.

Error in imwrite (line 419)
[data, map, filename, format, paramPairs] =
parse_inputs(varargin{:});`

Comment: If you look at what the map variable is, what do you see? Size and type of data?

If the map var. is empty, it means you have a gray scale or true color image.

In general, when I get weird stuff, 80% of times, you can get it to right format by either multiplying by 255 if the values are between 0 and 1, or divide by 255 to get the values between 0 and 1, also try to convert the data to type double, or type uint8, I have a feeling one of those combinations will work for you. Check out the doc for imwrite, MATLAB's image data formats are kinda a pain to learn

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had the same problem and it seems that one of the solutions is very simple. 
Just check whether you are passing a string as filenames for the destination file.

I was passing the output of the fullfile function (this one outputs a cell). What happens it that imwrite function parces the inputs (vargins) and looks for the first variable with char type. It uses this index to find the argument that specifies the datatype and consequently define the colormap. If your file path is a cell, it will get the wrong index and output strange errors.

I hope this helps